# Adding an image next to text in a form button css

Tags: javascript, html, css

i haven't been able to find anything on the internet so im not sure it can be done but i basically want to have my button with text then an image to the side. Here is my code so far -

```
<form method="post"  action="submit">
<p><input type="button" id="r-button"  value="Russian Dates  <!-- Russian Flag -->" onClick="return ClickT();" /></p>
</form>
<div id="info" style="display:none;">
Sat, 04 July 2015 - <a href="http://www.residentadvisor.net/event.aspx?723517">Outline </a>at KMZ - Moscow, Russia
</div>
```

The idea is the use clicks the button for the country the wish to view and and it shows the tour dates. Thank you for reading and any help would be appreciated  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to `button`

as like  this

```
<form method="post"  action="submit">
<p><button type="button" id="r-button"  value="  <!-- Russian Flag -->" onClick="return ClickT();">Russian Dates <img src="xyz.png" alt="" title="" /> </button></p>
</form>
```